# Types of technical fouls in NBA

Tags: rules, officiating, basketball, nba

Generally there are various types of technical fouls in NBA at what sort of situation which technical foul will be called?

Answer (score 5):

There are actually 15 categories of fouls in the NBA (depending on how you count).  Given the number of possibilities, most fans/announcers tend to treat fouls that are not "routine" as technical fouls, though some of the "special" fouls are actually personal fouls (they might still result in undefended free throws).

### Technical Fouls

- Delay of game - any action that would keep an opposing team from starting their possession

  - *This one is often bizarre as a player might inadvertently touch the ball after they score, but not stop and pass it to the referee.  A player may completely ignore the ball and run back on defense, but if they touch it, they have to pass it to the referee*
- Excessive timeouts - calling a timeout when the team has no more remaining

  - *Hi Chris Webber!  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-QPB9NBUG2g*
- Substitution - Not checking in with the officials before entering the court

  - *Loosely enforced*
- Hanging on the basket - Player cannot hang on the basket, net, etc except to avoid injury

  - *Barely enforced*
- Coaches box violations - Coach must stay within the markings and not run down the court

  - *Loosely enforced*
- Defensive 3-seconds - A defensive player in the lane must have been within arms reach of an offensive player in the last three seconds
- 5 players violation - You must have 5 players if the ball is alive

  - *There are actually exceptions to the fouling out rule so that a team always has at least 5 eligible players.  Cavs v Lakers this year ran into these exceptions.*
- Conduct - unsportsmanlike conduct

  - *The list here is a mile long, and almost completely at the referee's discretion.  An interesting case is that personal fouls committed while play is stopped can be assessed as techs*
- Fighting

  - *Punching someone may or may not be a technical foul, see the personal foul below.  Also there are no free throws at all if fighting is the foul assessed by the referee.  Everyone involved gets ejected*

### Personal Fouls

- Defensive - illegal contact by a defender

  - *This includes the "new" clear-path-to-the-basket and away-from-the-ball fouls*
- Offensive - illegal contact by an offensive player
- Loose ball - illegal contact when neither team has the ball
- Flagrant 1 - Unnecessary contact

  - *This one will not cause an ejection*
- Flagrant 2 - Unnecessary and excessive contact

  - *This one will cause an ejection*
- Punching - throwing a punch

  - *This one will cause an ejection*

Answer (score -3):

This is what [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technical_foul) has on technical fouls in basketball

> In basketball, a technical foul is any infraction of the rules
>   penalized as a foul which does not involve physical contact during the
>   course of play between opposing players on the court, or is a foul by
>   a non-player. The most common technical foul is for unsportsmanlike
>   conduct. Technical fouls can be assessed against players, bench
>   personnel, the entire team (often called a bench technical), or even
>   the crowd. These fouls, and their penalties, are more serious than a
>   personal foul, but not necessarily as serious as a flagrant foul.

Comment: This is sadly, incomplete, a discussion of NBA technical fouls needs to cover normal techs, flagrant 1s and flagrant 2s.

Comment: I thought a flagrant foul was a personal foul?